# How to change time slots format in fullcalendar

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

I want to customize fullcalendar time slots column like in below picture, thank your help.

Pls open this image =>> [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/i612R.png

Comment: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/slotLabelFormat gives you the possible options. I'm not sure what you're trying is possible. However it's also not necessary - the right-side time on each row is redundant, because you can already see it on the next line.

Comment: :) where is your code?

Comment: P.s. fullCalendar config has nothing at all to do with PHP or jQuery, so I changed your tags

Comment: Hello thanks for your help, actually the right side time i need for each row in this format for example 10:30 AM - 11:00 AM, i tried a lot but i could not find any option to implement

Comment: here is my code:     $(document).ready(function() {
   var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    editable:true,
    header:{
     left:'prev,next today',
     center:'title',
     // right:'agendaWeek'
    },

    slotDuration: '00:30:00',

    slotLabelInterval: 30,


    snapDuration: '00:30:00',
    // minTime: "08:00",
    // maxTime: "11:00",
    defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
    themeSystem: 'bootstrap',
      visibleRange: {
    start: '2021-03-22',
    end: '2021-05-25'
  },
    events: {
    url: 'get.php',
    type: 'GET',

  },


   });
  });

Comment: `actually the right side time i need `...but you don't, because it's already shown in the next line - as I previously explained. Don't clutter in your UI with duplicate information. It's obvious already where the time slot ends. And fullCalendar doesn't provide an option for what you want to do

Comment: Thank you for your advice i have founded the solution, i appreciate your help thank you

Comment: Hi, i know you have already solved the problem but next time please post your code as formatted text in the post. Posting your codes as a comment is hard to read. Anyways have a great day :D

Comment: If you found a solution please post it as an Answer below, for the benefit of others who may be thinking of something similar. That way others get help, and you get upvoted and more reputation points. This is how stackoverflow works - as explained in the [tour] - and you're allowed to answer your own questions.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Actually the problem is not sloved yet 100% we used the default format instead of what we were looking for, i tried to find it but i could not success

Comment: Thanks everyone, is there any way to allow limited selection in slots booking, like if someone trying to book multiple events so it should only allow some number of selection like 5 or 4 event at once

Comment: If you have a new, separate problem please ask a new question about it. People will generally not see or respond to questions placed in the comments. What I would say though, is start reading the articles at https://fullcalendar.io/docs/date-clicking-selecting to learn about possible options for solving your issue. You would obviously also need to employ some server-side checking at the time the booking is submitted to be saved, to ensure no-one else submitted into the same slot while the page was showing.

Comment: thanks, i have raised new new question

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69004494/how-to-allow-limited-selection-in-fullcalendar-available-timeslots-in-booking-pr