# how to allow limited selection in fullcalendar available timeslots in booking process

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-3

I want to allow only limited selection at once in full calendar booking process, for example only 5 or 4 slots can be booked at one time i tried to show better in the image pls check img attachment, Thanks

Image here https://i.stack.imgur.com/dLkYj.png

Here is my code

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
   var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    timeZone: 'America/Caraca',
     initialView: 'timeline',
     allDaySlot: false,

       views: {
    dayGridMonth: { 
    }
  },
     editable:true,
    header:{
     center:' ',//'prev,next today',
     left:'title',
     right:'<span></'
    },
businessHours: {
  // days of week. an array of zero-based day of week integers (0=Sunday)
  dow: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], // Monday - sunday

  start: '<?php echo $detData['stime']; ?>', // a start time (10am in this example)
  end: '<?php echo $detData['endtime']; ?>', // an end time (6pm in this example)
},
   
   events:{
        url: '<?php echo URL; ?>includes/action/teacher/booking_info.php',
       data: {home:'2',key:'<?php echo $teacherProfile['id']; ?>'},
        type: "GET",    

    },
     selectable: true,
      selectConstraint: "businessHours",
    select: function (start, end, jsEvent, view) {

        $("#calendar").fullCalendar('addEventSource', [{
            start: start,
            end: end,
            rendering: 'background',
            block: true,
        }, ]);

    },
    eventRender: function(event, eventElement) {
    if(event.status == 1) {
      eventElement.addClass('available');
    }
        if(event.status == 2) {
      eventElement.addClass('booked');
      eventElement.attr('data-bs-toggle','tooltip')
      eventElement.attr('data-bs-placement','top')
      eventElement.attr('title','Booked')


    }

     if(event.status == 3)
    {
       eventElement.addClass('booked-other'); 
    }
  
  },

   
   });
    $('.fc-content-col.booked').addClass('data-bs-toggletooltip')
  });
```

Comment: So you mean that, for example, at 1am on Monday there can only be maximum 4 bookings which start at that time?

Comment: Yes, just suppose i select only 3 events at home page each event contain on 30 mins so in the calendar page it should only allow me 3  slots, if the selection < 3 or greater than 3 it should not be allowed

Comment: That sounds like something different to what I said, and I'm not really sure what you mean exactly. Can you give a specific example?

Comment: just for example, your a teacher you provide multiple 30 mins lessons to book, if student select 3 lessons from lesson.php so the calendar should only allow them to book only three lesson instead of making further selection. hope now its clear

Comment: So it doesn't matter which times the user picks, the calendar must only allow them to choose 3 slots in the whole week? Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, exactly what i want

Comment: Ok so what have you researched and tried so far in order to try and make that work?  What steps do you think you will need in the process? Where are you stuck exactly? we're happy to help you if we can, but asking us is not a substitute for trying it yourself first. see [ask] for more guidance.